# boost::shared_ptr and assigning derived classes

Tags: c++, boost, variable-assignment, shared-ptr

Assume `DerivedClass` is derived from `BaseClass`
Would the following work?

```
boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> a(new BaseClass());
boost::shared_ptr<DerivedClass> b(new DerivedClass());
a=b;
```

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697329/question-on-assignment-with-boostshared-ptr-vs-the-reset-function), I understand that now `a` points to the derived and `b` points to the base (right?)

Also, now if I call a function via `a` would it call the derived implementation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
...
a=b;
```

You are reassigning to `a` and therefore `a` **and** `b` would now both point to the `DerivedClass` object. The `BaseClass` object would be destroyed, since its reference count would be zero at this point (by virtue of `a` being reasigned to point to a different object).

Since `a` now points to a `DerivedClass` object, virtual function calls (defined in `BaseClass` and overriden in `DerivedClass`) via `a` would call the corresponding member functions in `DerivedClass`.

When both `a` and `b` go out of scope, the `DerivedClass` object would be destroyed.

If you need to access functions specific to the derived class via `a` (e.g., non-virtual functions in `DerivedClass`), you can use:

```
boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedClass>(a)->SomeFunctionOnlyInDerivedClass();
```

Of course this is just a terse example that shows usage. In production code, you would almost certainly test for a successful cast to the `DerivedClass`, before dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Wouldn't a `static_pointer_cast` also work and thus be the preferred way of calling a non-virtual function in `DerivedClass`? `boost::static_pointer_cast<DerivedClass>(a)->SomeFunctionOnlyInDerivedClass();`

Answer (score 4):

> Assume `DerivedClass` is derived from `BaseClass`. Would the following work?

Yes. Just as there's nothing wrong with

```
boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> pbase(new DerivedClass());
```

(Assuming in both cases that BaseClass has a virtual destructor.) The smart pointer is designed to behave like a plain pointer as much as possible, and provide the same behaviour as `BaseClass* pbase = new DerivedClass();`, plus all that lifetime-management goodness.

> Following this question, I understand that now `a` points to the derived and `b` points to the base (right?)

No, a and b would both point to the DerivedClass instance. The swap that the linked article refers to happens on a temporary object inside *operator=*. When that temporary object goes out of scope, the BaseClass instance would be deleted.

> Also, now if I call a function via `a` would it call the derived implementation?

Yes. If you look at the implementation of *operator->*, all it does is return the pointer which the fundamental *operator->* is to be called on:

```
T * operator-> () const // never throws
{
    BOOST_ASSERT(px != 0);
    return px;
}
```

so that the behaviour is the same as a plain pointer.

Answer (score 3):

When doing a=b you tell a to point to the object b also points to. So all methods you call, you call on the BaseClass part of the object b points to.

So if it contains a virtual method that is overwritten in DerviedClass, the the overwritten version is called.